# Excel VBA: Controls have Two Names (was: Label Click event fails)

Tags: vba, excel, controls

My spreadsheet has labels that are created and removed dynamically. I have Click events for all of them (non-dynamic; the event code is always there). These are ActiveX labels on the sheet itself, not on a UserForm.

Intermittently, a label will be created that does not respond to clicking. I discovered that it's  because some labels don't **recognize** the name I gave them. In other words, clicking lblLong1 triggers **Label1_Click**, not **lblLong1_Click**.

I remember reading somewhere that controls actually have **two** names. At first they're both the same. It looks like sometimes, my macro reassigns one of the names, and the rest of the time it does the other.

Can someone educate me about the two names of controls? I may not be able to find the place I read it.

If it can't be fixed, can I come up with a workaround?

This is the code that creates the labels, based on the first three controls (which are always present). Only the "lblLong" ones should be clickable:

```
Sub ControlsCreate()

Dim chkBox As Object, lblShort As Object, lblLong As Object
Dim chkTemp As Object, shortTemp As Object, longTemp As Object
Dim i, NumEntries, NumLines

With Sheets("input view")
    Set chkBox = .Shapes("chkBox1")
    Set lblShort = .Shapes("lblShort1")
    Set lblLong = .Shapes("lblLong1")

    chkBox.Top = [narr].Top
    With lblShort
        .Visible = True 
        .Top = chkBox.Top
        .Left = [d1].Left + 10
        .Width = 107
    End With
    With lblLong
        .Top = lblShort.Top
        .Visible = lblShort.Visible
        .Left = lblShort.Left + lblShort.Width + 5
        .Width = 371
    End With

    If LCase([narrreco].Value) = "type" Then
        NumEntries = [tblrecotype].Rows.Count
    Else
        NumEntries = CutOffLeft([narrreco].Value, 4)
    End If


    For i = 2 To NumEntries
        Set shortTemp = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=lblShort.Left, Top:=chkBox.Top + 20 * i, Width:= _
            lblShort.Width, Height:=lblShort.Height)

        Set longTemp = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=lblLong.Left, Top:=chkBox.Top + 20 * i, _
            Width:=lblLong.Width, Height:=lblShort.Height)
        shortTemp.Name = "lblShort" & i
        longTemp.Name = "lblLong" & i
     Next i
 End With
End Sub
```

These are some of the click events for the labels:

```
Private Sub lblLong1_Click()
    Call LabelstoFields(Me.lblLong1.Caption)
End Sub

Private Sub lblLong2_Click()
    Call LabelstoFields(Me.lblLong2.Caption)
End Sub

Private Sub lblLong3_Click()
    Call LabelstoFields(Me.lblLong3.Caption)
End Sub
(Etc.)
```

Comment: May I see th code that you are using to create labels and assign click codes

Comment: I added the code. I also discovered something new about the issue. I read somewhere that controls actually have **two** names. I'll edit the original post to explain further.